# How can I use multiple VPNs for increased privacy?

Tags: vpn, dns, proxy, privacy

I've seen similar questions all with no answers, so I'll try to be specific.

The purpose is for increased privacy, in case the VPN service should turn over logs to law enforcement. You may be a political dissident, and only enjoy privacy until you violate a law in the country where the VPN service is registered or a more corrupt government comes into power.

can you use a service like hidemyass, stacked on top of ipvanish.

eg: configure ipvanish through the mac osx preferences as l2tp, and the second one using the hidemyass vpn app.

so websites you visit see hidemyass, but hidemyass only sees ipvanish ip.

not sure how to go about this.

thanks.

Comment: I'm hoping this question won't get deleted, so to clarify, i'm not shopping for a product recommendation. I've found there are tons of VPN's and some legit articles that discuss their privacy policy. I'm wondering if it is possible to use two in sequence and how to do it. I  mentioned the two products because one allows osx direct configuring and the other runs as an app.

Comment: given that i've just read 20 similar questions all without answers, I'm assuming this is for some reason impossible.  If someone could post "technically impossible" as an answer that would at least bring an end to what has been a recurring question. thanks again!

Comment: I don't think you'd have enough control over where the tunnel goes after the first connection.  So, suppose you hit HMA, you can't tell HMA to then forward you through ipvanish.  Of course, HMA is a terrible one that keeps logs forever.  [Here](http://torrentfreak.com/which-vpn-providers-really-take-anonymity-seriously-111007/) is a good list of VPNs, although slightly old now.

Comment: @user142485 - That is not fully accurate, your traffic is routed through that encrypted connection.  So if I have a connection to a VPN in London, I would absolutely appear to have a London IP, as I am also using those resources.  If they then want to obscure the IP address beyond that, then they could technically use a proxy.  Though that data, as we both know, would be outside of the encrypted connection.

Answer (score 3):

Your question really isn't clear here... and let me try to explain why:

Security is a subjective question.  It is best asked as: Secure from what?

If you're merely trying to obscure your IP address, there are hundreds of ways to accomplish that... and wrapping your connection in layers of VPNs will not make you any more *anonymous* than if you simply used 1 proxy service.

If you're trying to keep potential hackers from snagging credit-card numbers that may be sent in clear-text (or slightly-obscured)... it's just easier to rely on existing technologies that are already in-place like SSL.

If you're trying to keep traffic between two individuals very secure from people in the middle, you need to use a point-to-point encrypted tunnel (of some sort) that does not rely on 3rd parties.

Keep in mind that the quality of security is also a subjective matter.  Given enough computing power and enough time, almost any encryption used in the world today can be broken.  At some-point, you just have to say enough is enough and call it *safe*.

If you're asking us "how-to-evade-law-enforcement"... you're in the wrong place.

Comment: thanks compwiz. my goal is how to avoid being tracked back. thinking of freedom of speech... which could be evading law enforcement, just not for morally wrong purposes. the content of the info i want to post is not private since i'm posting it publicly... but i don't want it linked back to me. I understand there is the ip address but also dns leaking.

Comment: @user185164 But you need to clarify, are you trying to hide from the place your posting on, your ISP, or a 3rd party not involved in the act of posting. Things like DNS leaking only matter if you are concerned about the ISP tracking.

Comment: wow, thanks for cracking this open. I'm beginning to understand things a bit more. I'm trying to hide from the following: the blog I'm posting on, my isp I'm immediately connected to, and any attempts from people trying to trace the post back to me. It's not really the data since it is a public post. It seems a vpn/proxy product like the ones mentioned by Nerdwaller will do what I want, except dns leak may still be a problem. Also I thought somehow to use 2 of them in series would be additionally beneficial to further obscure my originating ip (basically one more step for someone to trace it)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are specifically trying to do this:

If I use a VPN provider I have to worry about them handing over my records.  If I use two, you (a government) have to get the records of both.  So this protects me more, correct?

I currently run a VPN from home.  That is, I connect to an L2TP VPN server at my house.  I use this because I want to protect myself while using free network access in the U.S. (I'm not a world traveller, but conceivably it would protect me there too).

Assume my server is a VPN provider, what would I do to VPN to the next hop (giving me two VPN connections)?

The server that provides my VPN connection is an OS X server.  So I would have to configure a VPN connection for the server to use, and tell it that all traffic destined for the Internet routes through that VPN connection.  I can configure this to happen, because I **OWN** the VPN server.  This would route **ALL** Internet destined traffic through the VPN (including any in my network).

I know of **NO** VPN provider that will configure **YOUR** tunnel to connect to another VPN provider.  So, technically is this possible?  Yes.  Is it going to happen in reality?  Probably not unless you are willing to pay a VPN provider a **LOT** of money.

You **CAN** go [Public VPN service]-->[Public Proxy].

Comment: hi, great answer, i think i understand this. so there is an option with the public proxy, but that one won't let me choose my city. Thank you Everett!